# Meteor contact form mailer error

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-packages

Trying to implemented the meteor-contact-form package into my meteor project and I keep receiving this error upon submission of contact form. I followed the guide on the github and am unsure why I keep getting this error.

```
Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' ReferenceError: check is not defined
```

Not sure if I need to do more than what is on the github repo. Can anyone guide me through what needs to be done.

https://github.com/bredikhin/meteor-contact-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the check package?
 `meteor add check`